# ServiceStack IoC Dependencies within dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, servicestack, inversion-of-control

I have an object that inherits from an Interface

```
public class Calculator : ICalculate
{
    public IDbConnectionFactory DbConnectionFactory { get; set; }
}
```

I have registered it in my apphost

```
container.RegisterAs<Calculator, ICalculate>().ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

When I go to use the DbConnectionFactory in the Calculator it is null.

```
public Calculator() 
{
    using (var db = DbConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
    {
        var x = db.Select<XObj>();  //db is null here
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the get of DbConnectionFactory resolve it?

How do I get IoC to know it has to create the DbConnectionFactory when it creates the calculator?

Comment: You need to add a constructor that has a parameter of type IDbConnectionFactory, so your instance can be injected. The DI isnt the same as MEF